# How can I solve the moment of inertia?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image: Moment of inertia]

The source tells me to use the formula for a ring, but it is not possible, as the portions are nearer to the axis than a normal ring. How can I find the moment of inertia?

Comment: After working out the moment of inertia of an arc of a ring about the axis through the centre of the ring, you may then be able to use the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: The $R$ in the drawing does not correspond to a radius.

Comment: The R is also the radius of the rings.

Comment: Thus angle subtended by each portion of ring at the corresponding centres become 60 degrees or pi/3 rad.

Comment: So for each ring, R is the radius of the ring and also the length of the chord that defines the minor arc pictured in the figure?

Comment: Yes. That leads you to use the integral form for moment of inertia, as of how I have found out. And you get : I = M(R^2)(5-(9(sqrt(3)/2)))/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that to solve this problem you will have to use the integral form for MoI.
$\int_0^Mr^2dm$ where $dm$ is the mass element (geometry of the problem) and $r$ is the distance from the axis of rotation.
You express the mass element in terms of $r$ so you get linear density.
Ex. Rod of mass $M$ has linear density $M/L$ so you get $dm=\frac MLdr$
Ex.2 A solid cylinder has volume density of $dm = \rho L2\pi rdr$ (density * length * circumference or $\rho dV$)
etc.
So, you find the distribution of mass (geometry) and plug it into the integral.

Another way you could solve it is by using the Parallel Axis Theorem ($PAT$)
$I_{parallel} = I_{cm} + Md^2$.
You know that the $I=\frac{MR^2}2$ for the whole ring.
To sum up, imagine that you have a whole ring, which you cut on both sides and you get a sort "brackety" system **()** (removing the "middle" part from  a nice round circle) which you can then solve using the integral method of $PAT$ method ($\frac{MR^2}2 + Md^2$ where $d$ is the distance from the axis and the same point where you cut to get one portion of the ring $->$ substituting)

Comment: What I wanted was there in the integral form. I solved it. Thanks although the rest of the answer was not of any direct help.

Comment: So, did I help in any way, if not, sorry, did my best. I gave both versions of coming to the  solution, one through direct integration of $r^2dm$ and one through manipulation of the parallel axis theorem.

Comment: Your help has been acknowledged, in the form of upvotes and in the form of 'Best Answer'.

Answer (score -1):

Use the parallel axis theorem for calculating the moment of inertia relative to a point which is not the center of mas (COM).  See for example [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem).

$I=I_{\rm COM} - m  d^2 ,$
where $d$ is the distance between COM and the point of rotation.